# "Route was not found" Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

I'm very new to Ember.js, so forgive if this is bad question:

I have a route defined as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('find', { path: 'find/:lat/:lon' });
});
```

Given this, I would expect a path such as `http://localhost/#/find/1/2` to work, and indeed, it does. However, In my IndexRoute, I have an action that does essentially the following:

```
var lat = 0; //I actually have logic here that grabs lat/lon from
var lon = 0; //HTML5 geolocator, but this is a simplified version
this.transitionTo('find/'+lat+'/'+lon);
```

When I trigger this action, I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The route find/0/0 was not found
```

I've looked at other similar questions and read through the docs but I can't find what's wrong. I'm sure it's a tiny mistake...Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transitionTo` builds up your url, you should pass ids, or model as arguments to `transitionTo` and let Ember build up your url.

```
this.transitionTo('find', 1, 2);
```

Here's an example with ids: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/royiyisi/1/edit

with a model: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/royiyisi/2/edit